# How to use date-fns with Vue class component?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, date-fns

Vue component:

```
<template>
  <div class="doc">
    {{ format(2019-08-11T08:13:13.750007, 'DD/MM/YYYY') }}
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import format from 'date-fns/format'

@Component
export default class Document extends Vue {
  public format: string | number | Date = ''
}
</script>
```

Throws an error: `Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.format is not a function"`

I suspect it's because `format` is considered a `Document` class property, and not the method from `date-fns`. How do I fix that? In plain JavaScript, it worked out of the box.

Comment: You've initialized `format` with empty string

Comment: @barbsan what should be in format? How do i refer to an imported `format`?

Comment: `public format` should be set to `format` from import and it's a function, not string | number | Date. Without typescript it would be `format: format`, so `public format: {type for function} format`?

Comment: indeed, i've tried `public format: any: format` and it worked, thanks. Btw, how do i type this `format`'s function?

Comment: It was just placeholder, I'm not that familiar with typescript. You may also take a look at [this](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/04/22/vue-js-libraries-plugins/), scroll to "A better way". Also you're missing quotes around `2019-08-11T08:13:13.750007`

Comment: What do you mean by "*how do i type this format's function?*"?

Comment: @barbsan i mean `public format: function = format`, format's type, there's no just function type in TS as i know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the class *property*, declare `format` as a class *method* that invokes the imported function:

```js
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import format from 'date-fns/format'

@Component
export default class Document extends Vue {
  format(date: string | number | Date, dateFormat: string): string {
    return format(date, dateFormat)
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks good, any downsides using it as class property instead?